# why object obj.two result's in undefined when declared

Tags: javascript

I create a object obj, but this.one results in undefined:

```
var obj = {
  one : 1,
  two : this.one  // this line results in undefined why
}
```

Why obj.two results in undefined?

Comment: Bit of a chicken and egg that one.. :)   Also in Javascript `this` refers to the object inside methods, your not inside any methods here, so this will equal `window`.  Try `var obj = { one: 1, two: this.Infinity }`  You will see `two` will equal `Infinity` because `Infinity` is part of `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the object, `this` is not the object yet, also the object is not even defined yet.

What you can do is:

```
var obj = {
  one: 1
}
obj.two = obj.one;
```